# this keyword in android

Tags: android

Why do we use the `this` keyword along with the method name in Android to call a method from another method within the same class. In Java or C# we can call other method directly without the `this` keyword, as in the code below.

```
public final String getElementValue( Node elem )
 {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null)
     {
         if (elem.hasChildNodes())
         {
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() )
             {
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  )
                 {
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str)
 {      
     NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);       
     return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the assumption in the question about the "this" requirement is incorrect .
it's the same as on java - you don't have to add the "this" keyword .

however , it is recommended to use it when you have multiple functions that have the same name , yet their scope is different (for example static vs normal functions) .

also , it is recommended that if the fields don't have a prefix (such as "m" or "_" ) , you should use "this" . you can also set eclipse to automatically add the "this" keyword for such cases .

Comment: What do you mean by the statement - "also , it is recommended that if the fields don't have a prefix (such as "m" or "_" ) , you should use "this" . you can also set eclipse to automatically add the "this" keyword for such cases ."

Comment: it's recommended so that you could differentiate between normal variables (inside functions) and those of the object's class.

Answer (score 8):

You don't **have to** use the `this` keyword in this case, it is done implicitly anyway. Sometimes it's clearer, and sometimes it makes Eclipse auto-complete the method name :P

Comment: I did not understand "Sometimes it's clearer, and sometimes it makes Eclipse auto-complete the method name".

Comment: At least in my computer, eclipse auto-completes method and variable names only if the object is specified before, so if I don't remember the exact method name I write - `this.` and get the full method name. Regarding clearer - it's really a matter of taste and style.

Answer (score 7):

I hope you get your answer but I just post here to provide extra understanding to whom who looking for this question.

`this` keyword represents current activity or class or object.

e.g.

```
private int number;

public example(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}
```

here, `this.number` represents `private int number` variable and number is methods `int number`

Now we can use "this" keyword as in inner class to represent current class,

```
public class ClassChaosActivity extends Activity {  

    public static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MyLoggingTag";  
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        final TextView myTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewToShow);  
        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonToClick);  
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {  

                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss a");  
                String strWhen = formatter.format(new Date());  
                myTextview.setText("Clicked at " + strWhen);  

                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "this Class name: " + this.getClass().getName());  
                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "this extends interface named: " + this.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getName());  
                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "this Enclosing class name: " +this.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getName());  
                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "this Is anonymous class? " + this.getClass().isAnonymousClass());  

                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "ClassChaosActivity.this Class name: " + ClassChaosActivity.this.getClass().getName());  
                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "ClassChaosActivity.this Super Class name: " + ClassChaosActivity.this.getClass().getSuperclass().getName());  
                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "ClassChaosActivity.this Is anonymous class? " + ClassChaosActivity.this.getClass().isAnonymousClass());  
            }  
        });  
    }  
}
```

the Log file is::

```
10-24 18:18:53.075: VERBOSE/MyLoggingTag(751): this Class name: com.androidbook.classchaos.ClassChaosActivity$1  
10-24 18:18:53.085: VERBOSE/MyLoggingTag(751): this extends interface named: android.view.View$OnClickListener  
10-24 18:18:53.085: VERBOSE/MyLoggingTag(751): this Enclosing class name:  com.androidbook.classchaos.ClassChaosActivity  
10-24 18:18:53.095: VERBOSE/MyLoggingTag(751): this Is anonymous class? true  
10-24 18:18:53.095: VERBOSE/MyLoggingTag(751): ClassChaosActivity.this Class name: com.androidbook.classchaos.ClassChaosActivity  
10-24 18:18:53.105: VERBOSE/MyLoggingTag(751): ClassChaosActivity.this Super Class name: android.app.Activity  
10-24 18:18:53.105: VERBOSE/MyLoggingTag(751): ClassChaosActivity.this Is anonymous class? false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write `return getElementValue(n.item(0));` and it will work. In general, `this` is used to dispel ambiguity, for example if a constructor's parameters have the same name as the attributes:

```
private int number;
public Example(int number) {
    this.number = number;  // here `this` is mandatory
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your example code, you may skip the keyword `this` as your method you are calling is with in the same class. However, the reason why we use **this** keyword is to reference to the same class' object while being inside that class.

As per java docs:

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.