# This pointer in java

Tags: java, android, this

I am new to java and android and want to understand how `this` works?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   
    private class  MyThread implements Runnable
    {    
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    loadingSection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            downloadImageUsingThreads(url);
        }
    }
}
```

What is `MainActivity.this`?

`MainActivity` is a class, so how does `MainActivity.this` works?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656097/this-keyword-in-android

Comment: Because you're code is running inside the context of `MyThread`, `this` points to the instance of `MyThread`, to allow you to reference the outer class, you need to use `MainActivity.this`, which returns the instance of the outer class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have pointers. However, `Object`(s) are implemented with references.

In your example, you have an inner class (`MyThread`). `MyThread` is accessing the instance of the outer class (`MainActivity`) within which it was *instantiated*.

Answer (score 2):

`MyThread` is an [inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) of `MainActivity`, so an instance of `MyThread` is associated with an instance of `MainActivity`.

With `MyThread` code, `this` refers to the instance of `MyThread`. To access the instance of `MainActivity`, you have to qualify it by writing `MainActivity.this`.

```
class A {
    int fieldA;

    class B {
        int fieldB;

        void methodB() {
            // This method can be executed for an instance of B,
            // so it can access the fields of B.
            this.fieldB = 13;

            // Since B is a non-static nested class of A,
            // it can also access the fields is A
            A.this.fieldA = 66;
        }
    }

    void methodA() {
        // This method can be executed for an instance of A,
        // so it can access the fields of A.
        this.fieldA = 42;

        // In order to create an instance of class B, you need
        // and instance of class A. This is implicitly done here.
        new B(); // The new B object is associated with the A
                 // object defined by 'this'.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is MainActivity.this?

the keyword `this` is indicating that you are passing as argument the actual instance of a class,

*which class?*: the **MainActivity** class