# What does Context in GeoCoder class of android signifies? Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context);

Tags: android

When i am applying this `Geocoder` in my Activity and using context as **`this`** ,then i m redirected to another activity I'm my android application.So i want to know that writing **`this`** keyword in `context` signifies what?

Comment: this is always signifies the current class object.. when you are passing this in activity its passing the object of activity which it self is a Context somehow

Answer (score 0):

The keyword **`this` represents the instance of the current class.**

You can access the properties and functions of the current class with `this` keyword.

For Simple Example,

Suppose, you activity name is MainActivity and you want to print `Toast` in Main Activity then just write:-

```
 Toast.makeText(this, "Hello...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here, just need to write `this` and automatically it takes instance of current Activity or class and display Toast message in Main activity.

> **`this` as `Context`**

The `Activity class` extends the `Context class` in android. Therefore `this` keyword can be used in the Activity class to **reference both** an `Activity object` and a `Context object` as an object.

> **And also other Multiple Usage this keyword**

- It can be used to refer current class instance.
- It used to invoke current class method (implicitly)
- It can be passed as an argument in the method call.
- It can be passed as argument in the constructor call.
- It also used to return the current class instance from the method.

You can also refer [**`this` keyword in android**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656097/this-keyword-in-android) for more understanding:-

Answer (score 0):

`this` always signifies the current class object.. when you are passing `this` in activity its passing the object of activity which it self is a `Context`

Lets say you have an `activity` and you add a `click listner` on button (i am juts writing a `sudo`)

```
 public class MyActvity extends AppcompatActivity{

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


             context=this;//here this will signigy the activity 
            navigationView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                     this //here this will be the object of clickListener
                   MyActvity.this//Now this is signifying the context 
                }
            });

    }

    }
```

I hope it helped

Comment: Not "somehow" - Activity is just subclass of Context. Look at inheritance tree of Activity: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity